# Items inside List disappear when saved and shown in a different List

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I'm sorry if the title is confusing but the issue I am facing is that, I have 2 List views, one shows the data stored in SwiftData (we'll call this SwiftData List), the other shows data retrieved from an API(we'll call this API List). Basically how the app works is that you search for grocery items which is retrieved from an API and when you tap on a List item, it is then saved to SwiftData and shown in the SwiftData List. The problem is that when I tap on an item in the API List, the whole list disappears. Here's the code:

**GroceryViewModel**

```
class GroceryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var context: ModelContext
    @Published var groceryItems: [GroceryItem] = []
    let apiManager = APIManager()
    
    init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.context = modelContext
    }
    
    func fetchDataFromAPI(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        apiManager.fetchDataFromAPI { [weak self] groceryItems, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { 
                if let groceryItems = groceryItems {
                    self?.groceryItems = groceryItems
                }
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveGroceryItem(_ item: GroceryItem) {
        context.insert(item)
        print("Added to grocery list")
    }
}
```

**GroceryListView (SwiftData List)**

```
struct GroceryListView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    @Query(sort: \GroceryItem.name) var groceryItems: [GroceryItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(groceryItems, id: \.id) { item in
                    GroceryItemCell(groceryItem: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AddGroceryItemView (API List)**

```
struct AddGroceryItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : GroceryViewModel
    @State private var isLoading  = false
    
    init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.viewModel = GroceryViewModel(modelContext: modelContext)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                List(viewModel.groceryItems) { item in
                    GroceryItemCell(groceryItem: item)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.saveGroceryItem(item)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        isLoading = true
        viewModel.fetchDataFromAPI {
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}
```

When I tap on an item in the API List, this function runs `viewModel.saveGroceryItem(item)` and this is when the API List disappears. But everything else works properly, like the data being saved to SwiftData and the SwiftData List showing all the items properly.

Comment: Change from `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject` since the view owns GroceryViewModel object.

Comment: In `AddGroceryItemView`, use `@StateObject var viewModel: GroceryViewModel`
 and initialise your `viewModel` with the `context` in `.onAppear{...}`, not
 in `init(...)`.

In your current `init(...)` you typically need something like:
 `self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: GroceryViewModel(modelContext: modelContext))`
to initialise a `StateObject`.